# Why are the results of a hive query split into multiple files

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I have a Amazon ElasticMapreduce job set up to run hive query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE output_dailies (
day string, type string, subType string, product string, productDetails string, 
uniqueUsers int, totalUsers int
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '${OUTPUT}';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE output_dailies
select day, type, subType, product, productDetails, count(distinct accountId) as uniqueUsers, count(accountId) as totalUsers from raw_logs where day = '${QUERY_DATE}' group by day, type, subType, product, productDetails;
```

After the job finishes, the output location, which is configured to be on S3, will contain 5 files with this pattern `task_201110280815_0001_r_00000x` where x goes from 0 to 4. The files are small, 35 KB each.

Is it possible to instruct hive to store the results in a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are created by different data nodes. Each one is appending to the file - if they all had to append to the same file then this would require lots of locking and slow it down.

You can treat the multiple files as one big file by just referring to the directory and all its contents.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Seems for my purposes I can just merge the contents into one file.

Comment: i am trying to find the one smallest date and the one greatest date from my logs of over 2 months of data. EMR is emitting the min-max dates from each of the different data nodes to 5 different output files. As a result i am getting 5 min dates and 5 max dates in 5 different output files. That's not serving my purpose? How do i condense them all into a single output file to find the ONE min date and the ONE max date over the entire data set?

Answer (score 2):

In general term yes this is achievable but with a loss of some scalability

Try using the setting

"set mapred.reduce.tasks = 1;"

This forces 1 reducer and therefore there will be only 1 file outputted.